# Symfony datetime field format is not working

Tags: php, symfony, date, datetime

My entity field is:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", name="date", nullable=true)
 */
protected $date;

function getDate() {
    return $this->date;
}

function setDate($date) {
    $this->date = $date;
}
```

Here I try to update the data base using below command database is updated

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

But if I try to insert `yyyy-mm-dd't'hh:mm:ss[2017-05-03T08:44:09+0000]` this format I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\epitacrm\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateType.php on line 44

How to change respectively this time format I am taking datetime datatype it is also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `$date` property in your entity, should be a `DateTime` object, not a formatted string like you're trying to do now.

Comment: Matczk   i am adding DateTime  as a datatype but i am getting error. How can i add  [2017-05-03T08:44:09+0000] this time format in the database  which data type can i use?

Comment: Both PHP `DateTime` object and SQL `DATE` type are binary types, so there's no such thing like "format". You will format these dates only when you're printing them. By the way, you're trying to handle datetime, but you're using date type in Doctrine.

Comment: Ok ok @Jakub Matczak Thanku so much i check my code

Comment: I got it @Jakub Matczak i am using                                                        function setDate($date) {
        $this->date = new \DateTime($date);
    }   like this and i store require format